pip installing packages via external tools
I am trying to install an internal python package via
pip install -r requirements.txt

requirements.txt
black 
numpy
scipy
interpackage @ git+ssh://git@github.com/.....
otherpackage @ git+ssh://git@github.com/....
tqdm


Due to security reasons, the cluster has disabled port forwarding.

To work with internal & external repositories  I am using gh-cli tool.


How can i modify the requirements.txt to use gh-cli tool when trying to clone external repositories?
Do I need to modify all requirements.txt in my package dependencies-chain ?
(E.g. do I need to manually modify requirements.txt for dep1-pkg & dep2-pkg)
                        ------------
                    |-->| dep1-pkg |
------------        |   ------------
| main-pkg | -------
------------        |   ------------
                    |-->| dep2-pkg |
                        ------------


I'm sorry, how does port forwarding relate to anything here? What do you mean with "To work with internal & external I am using gh-cli tool"?

w/o port forwarding  i cannot do a ssh clone of github repos (as required for interpackage)
gh-cli is a workaround to work github repos via my ssh-keys (even with port fowarding disabled).

Port forwarding is about incoming connections. You don't need those for cloning Git repositories over SSH. What happens when you actually to install requirements?

I end up with an error ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out          fatal: Could not read from remote repository. For my cluster I get the same error when cloning other repos over ssh.

Right. That means outgoing port 22 is firewalled or similar. There's no way gh-cli could get around that (unless you have an esoteric proxy setup); I'm pretty sure gh-cli is using git over HTTPS instead. That said, I don't think there is a mechanism in pip to automatically substitute git+https:// URLs for git+ssh:// URLs... :(

There is no a mechanism in pip to automatically substitute URLs. There is a mechanism in Git: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-config%5D+insteadof
